# Search active record for partial strings in a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need to perform a search on a single model Journal, after my product search results are returned.

Is there a way to search a Journal headline with only part of the full string?

```
def index
    @product_results = Gemgento::Search.products(params[:query])
    @editorial_results = Journal.where("headline LIKE ?", "#{params[:query]}")   
end
```

For example. Say my last journal object had the headline: "stack overflow blogpost"
if I query active record with:

```
@editorial_results = Journal.where("headline LIKE ?", "stack overflow")
```

As I have  it now, it still requires a direct match on  the string.

Searching through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html it seems that this is the correct way to do this, despite the warnings of sql injection.

Is there a way to structure the search so it will return the last entry? (without using a search library?)

Comment: try with `where("headline LIKE ?", "%stack overflow%")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the wildcard '%' before and after the search term.

```
def index
   @product_results = Gemgento::Search.products(params[:query])
   @editorial_results = Journal.where("headline LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")   
end
```

This means that anything can come before and after the query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `%` sign to your SQL query

```
def index
    @product_results = Gemgento::Search.products(params[:query])
    @editorial_results = Journal.
      where("headline LIKE :query", { query: "%#{params[:query]}%"})   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with `Journal.where("headline LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a case-insensitive search and you're using Postgres, use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`:
`Journal.where("headline ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")`

Adding this to hopefully save someone else the few minutes of frustration and embarrassment I just had, wondering why my lower-case search term wasn't returning any results for a title field where most words are capitalized.